# Unpack Set in Dataframe Value and Duplicate into Row

Tags: python, pandas

There is a pandas dataframe with a column of sets that maybe of any length:

```
n = np.nan
stack1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(  
         {'letter1': ['a','b','c','y'],
        'letter2': [ 'o','p', 'q', 'y'],
      'overlap': [ {'v'},{'c'}, {'c'}, {'v', 'c'}]
       })
stack1.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

[image]

From this dataframe, how can I unpack the contents of the set and create new rows from each of those unpacked elements?  It would be nice if the solution also worked for other containers like lists and tuples.

The desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [32]: col_to_unpack = 'overlap'

In [33]: df = stack1.copy()

In [34]: pd.DataFrame({
    ...:      col:np.repeat(df[col].values, df[col_to_unpack].str.len())
    ...:      for col in df.columns.difference([col_to_unpack])
    ...: }).assign(**{col_to_unpack:np.concatenate(df[col_to_unpack].map(list).values)})[df.columns.tolist()]
    ...:
Out[34]:
  letter1 letter2 overlap
0       a       o       v
1       b       p       c
2       c       q       c
3       y       y       c
4       y       y       v
```